# Overriding 'writeToParcel' is not allowed. Use 'Parceler' companion object instead

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, parceler

I used Jetbrains [plugin](https://github.com/nekocode/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin-kotlin) for generating Android Parcelable class in Kotlin, and got these two exceptions (not warnings, unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093364/android-kotlin-create-class-implement-parcelable-give-an-error-in-override-of), so the project doesn't build):

> CREATOR_DEFINITION_IS_NOT_ALLOWED: 'CREATOR' definition is not
> allowed. Use 'Parceler' companion object instead.
>
> OVERRIDING_WRITE_TO_PARCEL_IS_NOT_ALLOWED: Overriding 'writeToParcel' is not allowed. Use 'Parceler' companion object
> instead.

I have looked through similar questions, and didn't find any solutions for my case.

My Kotlin version: 1.1.51 (according to Gradle), but this feauture was added in 1.1.4: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/08/kotlin-1-1-4-is-out/

The auto-generated code:

```
@Parcelize
data class User(
        val id: Int,
        val cardId: String,
        val coefficent: Float = 1.0F,
        val name: String,
        val surname: String = ""
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
            source.readInt(),
            source.readString(),
            source.readFloat(),
            source.readString(),
            source.readString()
    )

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<User> = object : Parcelable.Creator<User> {
            override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): User = User(source)
            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<User?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }

    override fun describeContents() = 0

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) = with(dest) {
        writeInt(id)
        writeString(cardId)
        writeFloat(coefficent)
        writeString(name)
        writeString(surname)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *either* use `@Parcelize` to tell the compiler to add the methods, *or* implement them explicitly (generated by IDEA plugin or not, it doesn't matter). It doesn't make sense to have both at once.

You can customize logic used by `@Parcelize`, but it's still not done by overriding the methods, but as described in https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/android-parcelable.md#custom-parcelables (that's what the "Use 'Parceler' companion object instead" part of the message means).